# Sort Array from Nearest to Farthest Distance from IP

Tags: svelte

I am not finding a way to sort my array based on the shortest to farthest distance from the IP of the user who is accessing the webApp.

I have a component for the items, (the cards)

ListingItem.svelte:

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    export let listing
    export let id
    let position = null
            
    onMount(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
            position = pos
        })
    })

    $: distance = position ? getDistance(position) : 0

    function getDistance(pos) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude
        var lng = position.coords.longitude
        var latlng1 = {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
        }
        var latlng2 = {
            lat: listing.geolocation.lat,
            lng: listing.geolocation.lng
        }

        // calculate the distance between latlng1 and latlng2
        return getDistanceFromLatLngInKm(latlng1, latlng2)
    }

    function getDistanceFromLatLngInKm(latlng1, latlng2) {
        var R = 6371 // Radius of the earth in km
        var dLat = deg2rad(latlng2.lat - latlng1.lat) // deg2rad below
        var dLon = deg2rad(latlng2.lng - latlng1.lng)
        var a =
            Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(latlng1.lat)) *
                Math.cos(deg2rad(latlng2.lat)) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2)
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))
        var d = R * c // Distance in km
        return d
    }

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
    }

 </script>

<div>   
    <p>
    {listing.name}
    </p>
    <p>
    {listing.location}
    </p>
    <p>
    {distance.toFixed(2)} km from you 
// I get distance from the function above // it works nice
    </p>
</div>
```

I use the component inside my index.svelte:

```js
<script>
....  fetchListings from Firebase
const params = [
 listingsRef,
 where('type', '==', 'all'),
 orderBy('timestamp', 'desc'),
 limit(9)
  ] // order by descending
... other things ...
</script>

<div>
    {#await fetchListings()}
        {#if loading}
            <div>
                <StretchLoader/>
            </div>
        {:else if listings && listings.length > 0}
            <ul>
                {#each listings as listing (listing.id)}
                    <div class="grid-items">
                        <ListingItem listing={listing.data} id={listing.id} />
                    </div>
                {/each}
            </ul>
        {/if}
    {/await}
</div>
```

I pass the data that is inside Firebase via props to ListItem.svelte:

```
<ListingItem listing={listing.data} id={listing.id} />
```

I need an approach (help) to solve this problem. And sort the array based on the shortest to farthest distance from the IP of the user who is accessing the webApp.

Comment: Instead of calculating the distance inside the ListingItem component it might be better to move this logic after the loading of the the listings from the db and add the distance information to the listing objects

Comment: Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
    ...

    async function fetchAndSort() {
        const listings = await fetchListings()
        try {
            const currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition()
            const listingsWithDistance = listings.map(listing => {
                listing.distance = getDistance(currentPosition, listing)
                return listing
            })
            return listingsWithDistance.sort((l1, l2) => l1.distance - l2.distance)
        }catch(e) {
            // error while getting currentPosition > no need to sort
            // either map distance to 0 or handle missing d. in ListingItem
            return listings
        }
    }

    function getCurrentPosition() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject)           
        })
    }

</script>

{#await fetchAndSort() then listings}
    {#each listings as listing (listing.id)}
        ...
    {/each}
{/await}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: ```index.mjs:2062 Uncaught (in promise) Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects.```

Comment: @RicardodePaula What's `listings` in this case then?

Comment: listings is a collection of documents : https://imgur.com/a/koGPzC2

Comment: In firestore, yes. But after fetching there should be an array of objects. What if you console.log `listings` after `const listings = await fetchListings()`?

Comment: ```undefined```

Comment: Then fetchListings() doesn't do what it should :) But it's impossible to help with that, without seeing its content... Since your #await block was missing the `then` - do you have the listings as a local variable which `fetchListings()` sets instead of returning the listings? (In that case remove `const listings =` and just `await fetchListings()`)

Comment: No, fetchListings() are correct.  If I place console.log(listings) after {#await ...} i get the results: https://imgur.com/a/1KnTjl3 https://imgur.com/pDfeNU4

Comment: Removing  remove ```const listings =``` I grab the data in ```fetchAndSort()``` function but the list remains unsorted

Comment: `fetchListings()` seem to only write listings to a variable. Change it so the listings are also returned from the function call and try again with the original code of my answer

Comment: (If the list remains unsorted, there might also be an error getting the currentPosition. You might also add a log there to check that's not the case)

Comment: It's working. I get the current position from ```getCurrentPosition()``` I just get this warning: ```'listingsWithDistance' is declared but its value is never read.```

Comment: And that's so true... it should be `return listingsWithDistance.sort(...)`

Comment: Your function is perfect but is not working for me, I think that I have to remove the logic inside ListItem.svelte and put it in the index page

Comment: You mean `getDistance()`?

Comment: Yes. I think I have to pass it to index.sevelte and find a way to pass it as props to ListItem.Svelte

Comment: @RicardodePaula You can either move all three dependent functions `getDistance, getDistanceFromLatLngInKm, deg2rad` to index.svelte or better put them in a seperate .js file and just import `getDistance` from there and add the additional parameter to `getDistance(pos, listing)`